# Mendeley issue with two author citation and bibliography (& vs. ir)

Tags: customization, author, citations, bibliography, mendeley

Mendeley appears to have an issue with in text citation for two authors, where instead of (Author & Author Year) it produces (Author ir Author Year). It seems to have an issue with printing "&" and instead prints "ir". The same for the bibliography, see example below. It seems to be fine to print "&" in the Journal name, just not for two authors. Perhaps custom coding within Mendeley? Anyone know how to tackle this?

Example of in-text:
Insert text for example (Belitz ir Lang 2008)

Example of Bibliography:
Belitz, C., ir S. Lang. 2008. Simultaneous selection of variables and smoothing parameters in structured additive regression models. Computational S. & Data Analysis 53:61-81.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you're using a CSL style that uses a text term (like "and") between authors, and which is localized to Lithuanian (the Lithuanian CSL locale file specifies "ir" as translation for "and": https://github.com/citation-style-language/locales/blob/cbb45961b815594f35c36da7e78154feb5647823/locales-lt-LT.xml#L25).

If you wish to have the ampersand ("&") separating authors, you need a style that uses `<name and="symbol"/>` instead of `<name and="text"/>` (see https://docs.citationstyles.org/en/stable/specification.html#name).

Comment: Thank you, Rintze. Your share answered my question. I was able to identify the right CSL needed for the publication I aim to send my work to. Thank you!